# Azure Domain broken

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-dns

everyone.

I recently bought a domain on azure and I can't bind it to an app service (web app).

When I try to bind a domain it says "*App Service Domain is in a broken state. Please navigate to the App Service Domain resource and delegate to Azure DNS before adding hostname.*"

When navigating to the domain at https://resources.azure.com, it looks my dnsZoneId is assigned to another resource group and I don't know how to change it.

I tried to delete the DNS zone and recreate it but I can't bind the dns back from https://dcc.secureserver.net

Can Anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Newest**

About how to change your dnsZoneId to another resource group, you can read [this post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/31472749--domain-move-to-another-resource-group-subscripti). I think it useful to you.

**PRIVIOUS**

Under normal circumstances, this problem does not occur, because when you successfully purchase a domain in azure, all information and services of the domain name are hosted on azure.

There is [a similar case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/79705ddd-2abd-4cc5-8636-15ee58d81fdf/domain-is-in-a-broken-state?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) here, you can refer to it. May be helpful to you.

If there is a problem, I guess the reason is:

1. Some of your misoperations may cause the domain name service or settings to be configured incorrectly, making it unusable. (This probability is relatively low)
2. It may be the domain management service of azure, there may be a problem in your region. It may take a while to try again, or transfer the domain name to godaddy for management. (The reason for this is because I have encountered it in godaddy before, but it was solved after migrating the domain name to Tecent in China)
3. If the above operations have been tried and cannot be solved, please raise a ticket in the portal for help.

Comment: You can try according to my method, if you can help you solve or need other help, you can contact me and look forward to your reply.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Your answer guided me to the solution. I deleted the DNS zone and followed a tutorial to migrate from https://dcc.secureserver.net to azure dns zone and it reset everything. It is now working!. Thank you, my friend.